# Recursive diff on directories says files differ, but no output when I diff on the files

Tags: linux, terminal, diff

(in the Linux Terminal)

I used

```
diff --recursive --brief dir1 dir2
```

and it tells me that

```
File dir1/file and dir2/file differ
```

But then, I try:

```
diff dir1/file dir2/file
```

and there is no output (which I assume means it found no differences between the files this time).... What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I think your --brief is the problem ... without this option also it will only compare files with same name..

Comment: According to the man page, `--brief` only outputs whether files differ. So I don't see any connection with the OP's problem.